# re-change a control properties with same input on C# (In this case,button)

Tags: c#, winforms

i don't know if this is a silly,dumb,etc question about C#,since i'm very new to this

i have a *control* (in this button) with this code

```
private void A19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   A19.Text="X";
}
```

What i'm asking is how to change it's *Text* property into other text or return to it's previous value when it's re-clicked ?

any ideas ?

(Visual Studio 2012,Windows Form,using .NET Framework 4)

Thankyou.

Comment: Please show us an example of result you want to achieve

Comment: For example when i click the button,its *Text* property change to "X" and when i click again the same button the text will comeback to it's previous value,or other text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To switch between two values add a boolean.

```
private bool displayOriginalText = false;
private void A19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(displayOriginalText)
      A19.Text="X";
   else
      A19.Text="Y";
   displayOriginalText = !displayOriginalText;
}
```

To switch between multiple;

```
private List<string> words = new List<string> {"first", "second"};
private uint currentIndex = 0;
private void A19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   A19.Text=words[currentIndex % words.Count];
   currentIndex++;       
}
```

Comment: Your second example will throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException indexing the words list if your signed integer wraps round to negative numbers resulting in a possible remainder of -1. Changing to an unsigned int will prevent this.

Comment: I can't remember the time I pressed the same button 100 times in a program during a single use nevermind 2,147,483,647.. I think its pretty safe

Comment: These things always bite you when you least expect! Someone else might change this slightly to run thousands of times meaning it is a bug waiting to happen. It's always good to program defensively if you can.

Comment: I've changed it for the sake of it, and while I agree with your defensive programming approach, I do not believe in this particular instance the OP would have any need to run this code the 2.1 billion times required to break it

Comment: I read your last few words in dead pan way(!) I'm not criticising your code; I'm just bringing it to your attention if you weren't already aware. Something the OP being new to C# will perhaps benefit by programming defensively....Someone could set the private variable to a negative value for some bonkers reason and it could throw on the first call - uint won't let that happen.

Comment: how if i put boolean in each _button_ with diffrent name (i.e. dOTA9,dOTB10,etc) it means it won't distrub the other _button_ boolean right ?
and,what is (!) mean ?

Comment: Id suggest either overriding the button class with your own that can hold its different values and a boolean, but I'd question if its really buttons that you need if you need to change as many as 10.. ! Means not or opposite of if you like so in this case not true/false

Answer (score 1):

Create 3 private member variables in your form class

E.g.:

```
string _currentString = "X";
string _previousString = string.Empty;
bool _state = true;
```

Then in your click event handler:

```
if(_state)
{
    A19.Text = _currentString;
}
else
{
    A19.Text = _previousString;
}

// Or A19.Text = _state ? _currentString : _previousString

_state = !_state;
```

Whenever you change `_currentString`: Ensure you set `_previousString = _currentString` before you set `_currentString`.